# Removing an Item from a dropdown when selected in another dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, html, drop-down-menu

This page will have 16 dropdown boxes, when I select an item from each of them, I'd like it to be removed from all the others.

This is for a football lineup page, if that helps you picture the scenario.

I hope this isn't too vague and I'm clear in what I'm struggling with.

Thanks :)

I am using in the whole project: HTML, PHP, Javascript, AJAX

```
<select name="pl1">
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>

<select name="pl2">
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>

<select name="pl3">
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>

<select name="pl4">
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>
```

Comment: a little bit of detailed code on what's not working would be helpful.

Comment: I haven't written anything for this yet, I'm not sure how I would remove it.... erm... here is what the code will look like....

`<select name="pl1">
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
 </select>
<select name="pl2">
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
 </select>
<select name="pl3">
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
 </select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript solution:

```
function check() {
  d=document;
  myArray = [];
  for (h=0;h<4;h++) {
    myArray[h] = d.getElementById('pl'+(h+1)).value;
  }
  for (a=0;a<4;a++) {
    for (b=1;b<5;b++) {
    d.getElementById('pl'+(a+1)).options[b].style.display = "block";
      for (c=0;c<4;c++) {
        if(d.getElementById('pl'+(a+1)).options[b].value == myArray[c]) {
          d.getElementById('pl'+(a+1)).options[b].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="pl1" onchange="check();">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>

<select id="pl2" onchange="check();">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>

<select id="pl3" onchange="check();">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>

<select id="pl4" onchange="check();">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Ben</option>
  <option value="2">Jack</option>
  <option value="3">James</option>
  <option value="4">John</option>
</select>
```

Make sure you use id and not name on your select's

Comment: thanks, is there a way to re add the something too? in this example... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061289/when-changing-a-value-in-a-dropdown-menu-the-old-value-is-put-into-the-others

Comment: Updated it to allow them to show again. Also added the blank option you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var selects = $('select.magic-select');
                $(selects).bind('change', function (evt) {
                    var newVal = $(this).val(), oldVal = $(this).data('old-val');

                    if (newVal != 0) {
                        $(selects).not(this).find('option[value="' + newVal + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }

                    $(selects).not(this).find('option[value="' + oldVal + '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(this).data('old-val', newVal);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            $players = array('Ben', 'Jack', 'James', 'John', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Allmighty Foobar');
            $numPlayers = count($players);

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numPlayers; $i += 1) {
                printf('<select class="magic-select" name="pl%s" size="%s"><option value="0"></option>', $i, $numPlayers + 1);

                foreach ($players as $j => $name) {
                    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $j + 1, $name);
                }

                echo '</select>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that `magic-select` as a class name is not a must. It could be anything, but you'll have to adjust the javascript accordingly.

Comment: +1, as you're using PHP, you should also use this one to loop on your players and create the multiple selects from a single source of data. You can also generate the `<select>` once, and clone it in Javascript (probably cleaner).

Comment: sorry to be a pain, is there any change you could also show me how to add them back if they're unselected and have them all start on a blank option... so <option value="0"></option>

Comment: @Stephen I changed the code. Hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much Yoshi,
I have accepted Tokes's answer as that one doesn't use jquery or any other prebuilt librarys, my apoligies, I forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 0):

Prototype solution:

```
$$('select').each(function(item) {
    Event.observe(item, 'change', function(e) {
        var el = e.srcElement;
        var val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        $$('select').each(function(item) {
            if (item != el) {
                for (var i = 0; i < item.options.length; i++) {
                    if (item.options[i].innerHTML == val) {
                        item.removeChild(item.options[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qrhe7/

Comment: who uses prototype anymore? xD

Comment: @yes123: Unfortunately, my company :(

Comment: lol ok... talk with your boss or send an anonymous email with jquery website xD

Answer (score 0):

I have taken @Tokes answer and made it a little more understandable and added some jQuery to it for dropdown and option selection. I am providing this incase someone struggles with getting it implemented. I am using the most direct selectors possible so jQuery doesn't have to work so hard. I am using this logic on 68 drop downs with 68 options in it, the performance was kinda bad when I started due to jQuery and the amount of for loops I was using but now it is really snappy so I hope someone gets some use out of it. Thanks Tokes your answer helped for my situation :)

```
function _updateDropdowns() {

    // gather selects with class so we dont grab all
    var select = $('#tbl_fieldMap select.table-fields');

    // store used fields
    var used = [];

    // collect all selected values
    for (var x = 0; x < select.length; x++) {

        // get selects value
        var val = select[x].value;

        // dont add empty
        if (val != '')
            used[x] = val;
    }

    // foreach select box
    for (var a = 0; a < select.length; a++) {

        // get options that matter (excludes 'default entry')
        var options = $(select[a]).children('.table-option');

        // foreach option in select
        for (var c = 0; c < options.length; c++) {

            // current option
            var opt = options[c];

            if ($.inArray(opt.value, used) > -1) {
                // hide if already used
                opt.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                // show if not used
                opt.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**.data()** = Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.

**.not()** = Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

**.on()** = will attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements(change in this case)

**.find()** = Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element. in this case well find the element that has been used and put in in a var named prevValue, then we check if there is a match with the other selection fields and then removes those from the selection options.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('select').on('change', function(event ) {
   var prevValue = $(this).data('previous');

$('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+prevValue+'"]').show();    
   var value = $(this).val();

    $(this).data('previous',value);         
    $('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();

  });

});
```

Comment: You are answering a very old question. It's not clear to me why your answers is better than the others (there already is an accepted answer). Furthermore, you are using jQuery while the question didn't mention jQuery at all.