# Changing items of drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have four drop down lists on my page:

```
1. A  
  -100  
  -75  
  -50  
  -25  

2. B 
3. C  
4. D
```

When I chose 100 in drop down A, the other drop downs should have the items from A except the chosen one.  It should be like this:

```
1. A  
  -100  

2. B 
  -75  
  -50  
  -25  

3. C  
  -75  
  -50  
  -25  

4. D  
  -75  
  -50  
  -25
```

The same for the other drop downs when one has been selected.  It should look like this:

```
1. A  
  -100  

2. B 
  -75   

3. C   
  -50  

4. D   
  -25
```

How could I do this?

Here is the only code I've made:

```
<select id = "A" name = "A">
    <option value = "c1">-a-</option>               
    <option value  = "100">100</option>
    <option value  = "75">75</option>
    <option value  = "50">50</option>
    <option value  = "25">25</option>
</select>  

<select  id = "B" name = "B">
    <option value = "c2">-b-</option>   
</select>

<select id = "C" name = "C">
    <option value = "c3">-c-</option>   
</select>

<select  name = "D" id = "D">
    <option value = "c4">-d-</option>   
</select>
```

Comment: "I have four dropdown list in php" - No, you don't. PHP is server side scripting, there's no user interface in PHP.

Comment: @k102 - how can i achieve it by js?.

Comment: @Martin - what do you mean by i don't?

Comment: You should definitely post some of your code here and probably retag your question to html, javascript.

Comment: you *can* do it by php if you're making a server request every time a dropdown is changed. not very convenient though.

Comment: half-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060003/removing-an-item-from-a-dropdown-when-selected-in-another-dropdown

Comment: @Yoshi - that was definitely whats i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(e){
        var selectedObj = $(this);

        selectedObj.nextAll().each(function(i, ele) {
            $(ele).html('');
            selectedObj.children('[value!='+selectedObj.val()+']').each(function(j, option){
                $(ele).append($(option).clone());
            });
        });
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="a" id="a">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
</select>

<select name="b" id="b">
    <option value="-">-</option>
</select>

<select name="c" id="c">
    <option value="-">-</option>
</select>

<select name="d" id="d">
    <option value="-">-</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using ajax call and then loading the content you want and this can also be achieve by using simple javascript.

```
<?php
$type=$_GET["q"];
switch($type)
{ case '100': ?>
<select class="select" name="subtype" id="subtype">
  <option value="c2" >-b-</option>
  <option value="75">75</option>
<?php break; ?>
```

Make necessary changes to this code after ajax call and this will help.