# Removing an option from all other chosen multiple dropdowns, when selected on a particular dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I have attached a JS Fiddle link here:

http://jsfiddle.net/p0b4j5o8/18/

If you check the fiddle link, you will see that I have written JavaScript/jQuery code (a function named `add_mitigator()`) in the HTML section.

When I used to write the code in the JavaScript section, Firebug used to trigger an error stating `function add_mitigator() isn't defined`.
But when I wrote the same in the HTML section instead, it runs with no problem. I am not much accustomed with JS Fiddle. How can I write a function in `function_name()` format in the fiddle?

In my JS Fiddle, there is a dropdown (chosen multiple) with options 1 to 10. When I click on the `add_mitigator` link, it creates/appends a new chosen dropdown.

Suppose I have three dropdowns, then if I select `2 from dropdown 1`, then the other dropdowns will have 2 removed from their options. When I will unselect the 2 from the first dropdown, then 2 will again  be available in the other two dropdowns. This should act vice-versa. When 2 is selected from any dropdown, then it is unavailable for all other dropdowns.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please don't rely so much on an external site. Put your script here with all relevant information and state a clear question (about your problem not about how to use some other site). That said, your particular problem is asked quite often, have you done some research here on SO before asking? I'm quite sure you'll find a lot of duplicates.

Comment: @Yoshi, That particular question isn't asked before... Can u please state the link stating similar queries?

Comment: This one for example is pretty much exactly what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6060003/697154

Comment: @Yoshi I disagree that this is a duplicate. This is specific to the chosen plugin whereas the link you've provided is not. I have a fix specific to chosen for this

Comment: @Saswat here's a fix for your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/p0b4j5o8/21/ I'll post a decent answer response as soon as this is reopened as this should not have been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @JakoBasson The question does not even mention a plugin. This is only visible inside the jsfiddle. And thus, one cannot really tell if this is a question about the plugin or if the plugin is just used for demonstrating purpose.

Comment: Well if one reads carefully this part highlights the plugin used "When i click on the add_mitigator link, it creates/appends a new chosen dropdown.". I managed to figure it out by reading his question, granted it could be constructed better, but its completely valid imo.

Comment: I removed the duplicate flag. Please post your answer. Let's have the author decide.

Comment: I clearly mentioned in the tags, jquery-chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling the function below on the select box change event the options will be disabled/enabled as per your requirements.

```
function disableSelectedValues() {
    var cssOptions = [];
    $(".input_field.criteria_countries option").removeAttr("disabled");
    $.each($(".input_field.criteria_countries"), function(index, select) {
        cssOptions = [];
        var values = $(select).val();
        if (values) {
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                cssOptions.push("option[value=" + values[i] + "]");
            }
        }
        console.log("test");
        if (cssOptions.length) {
            // disable all options with the selected values
            $(".input_field.criteria_countries " 
+ cssOptions.join(",.input_field.criteria_countries ")).attr("disabled", true);

            // enable all options with the selected values for the current select
            $(select).find(cssOptions.join()).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

With `.chosen` you can listen to onchange events with `.chosen().change();`. 
In the `.chosen().change()` event you then need to tell all of the select boxes to update once a value has changed. By using `.trigger("chosen:updated");` on the select box selectors whenever a change event is fired, the select boxes will update.

**NOTE** that you will need to call the `disableSelectedValues()` function whenever you add a select box to have its options disabled on creation.

http://jsfiddle.net/p0b4j5o8/22/

Comment: @JaskoBasson    bro your answer is just a beauty... however there is a small glitch.... say i have drop 1 from before, then I add a new drop2.. I select 2 from drop1 and 3 from drop2. Now i click on add mitigator.. A new drop3 will be created, but the 2and 3 are still selectable from this new drop3

Comment: @Saswat updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p0b4j5o8/22/ should be fine now. You also need to call the function whenever a new select is added